# Applying union() on same model is not recognising ordering using GenericRelation

Tags: django, django-orm

I have an Article model like this

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.db import models
from hitcount.models import HitCountMixin, HitCount

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(
    HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk',
    related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')
```

when I do `Article.objects.order_by('hit_count_generic__hits')`, I am getting results.but when I do

```
articles_by_id = Article.objects.filter(id__in=ids).annotate(qs_order=models.Value(0, models.IntegerField()))
articles_by_name = Article.objects.filter(title__icontains='sports').annotate(qs_order=models.Value(1, models.IntegerField()))
articles = articles_by_id.union(articles_by_name).order_by('qs_order', 'hit_count_generic__hits')
```

getting error

> ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set

How can i achieve union like this? I had to use union instead of AND and OR because i need to preserve order. ie; articles_by_id should come first and articles_by_name should come second.

using Django hitcount for hitcount https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount. Hitcount model is given below.

```
class HitCount(models.Model):
"""
Model that stores the hit totals for any content object.
"""
hits = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
content_type = models.ForeignKey(
    ContentType, related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
object_pk = models.TextField('object ID')
content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk')

objects = HitCountManager()
```

As suggested by @Angela tried prefetch related.

```
articles_by_id = Article.objects.prefetch_related('hit_count_generic').filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3]).annotate(qs_order=models.Value(0, models.IntegerField()))
articles_by_name = Article.objects.prefetch_related('hit_count_generic').filter(title__icontains='date').annotate(qs_order=models.Value(1, models.IntegerField()))
```

the query of the prefetch_related when checked is not selecting the hitcount at all see.

```
 SELECT "articles_article"."id", "articles_article"."created", "articles_article"."last_changed_date", "articles_article"."title", "articles_article"."title_en", "articles_article"."slug", "articles_article"."status", "articles_article"."number_of_comments", "articles_article"."number_of_likes", "articles_article"."publish_date", "articles_article"."short_description", "articles_article"."description", "articles_article"."cover_image", "articles_article"."page_title", "articles_article"."category_id", "articles_article"."author_id", "articles_article"."creator_id", "articles_article"."article_type", 0 AS "qs_order" FROM "articles_article" WHERE "articles_article"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I am using Django 2.2.3

Comment: Can you try to update the question with the SQL representations of your 3 last queries?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Have you checked the prefetch_related queries? Also can you add the HitCount Model?

Answer (score 0):

From [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union):

> Further, databases place restrictions on what operations are allowed in the combined queries. For example, most databases don’t allow LIMIT or OFFSET in the combined queries.

So, make sure that your database allows combining queries like this.

Answer (score 0):

> ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set

You are getting this error, because that's exactly what's happening. Your final result-set for *articles* does not contain the hits column from the *hitcount table* , due to which the result-set cannot order using this column.

Before delving into the answer, let's look at what's happening with your django querysets under the hood.

**Retrieve a particular set of articles and include an extra ordering field qs_order set to 0.**

```
articles_by_id = Article.objects.filter(id__in=ids).annotate(qs_order=models.Value(0, models.IntegerField()))
```

**SQL Query for the above**

```
Select id, title,....., 0 as qs_order from article where article.id in (Select ....) # whatever you did to get your ids or just a flat list
```

**Retrieve another set of articles and include an extra ordering field qs_order set to 1**

```
articles_by_name = Article.objects.filter(title__icontains='sports').annotate(qs_order=models.Value(1, models.IntegerField()))
```

**SQL Query for the above**

```
Select id, title, ...1 as qs_order from article where title ilike '%sports%'
```

**Original queryset and order_by hit_count_generic__hits**

```
Article.objects.order_by('hit_count_generic__hits')
```

This will actually perform an inner join and fetch the hitcount table to order by the hits column.

**Query**

```
Select id, title,... from article inner join hitcount on ... order by hits ASC
```

**Union**

So when you do your union, the result-set of the above 2 queries is combined and then ordered using your *qs_order* and then *hits* ...where it fails.

**Solution**

Use prefetch_related to get your hitcount table in the initial queryset filtering, so you can then use the hits column in the union to order.

```
articles_by_id = Article.objects.prefetch_related('hit_count_generic').filter(id__in=ids).annotate(qs_order=models.Value(0, models.IntegerField()))
articles_by_name = Article.objects.prefetch_related('hit_count_generic').filter(title__icontains='sports').annotate(qs_order=models.Value(1, models.IntegerField()))
```

Now as you have the desired table and its columns in both your SELECT queries, your union should work the way you have defined.

```
articles = articles_by_id.union(articles_by_name).order_by('qs_order', 'hit_count_generic__hits')
```

Comment: thanks for spending time on this issue. Added the prefetch_related but the issue is still there.  Getting " ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set"

Comment: can you check what query is executed after you add the prefetch_related for the first two queries? Also add your HitCount Model to the question please.

Comment: sorry to get back late.  Added the hitcount model to the question. Also adding the prefetch_related query.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Can you also add the *prefetch_related* django code that you used for prefetching both articles and articles_by_name ?

Comment: added to question. Please take a look.

Answer (score -2):

Just replacing `prefetch_related` with `select_related` works for me.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related